# Why don't my options get appended to all selects

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I want to generate an arbitrary number of options and append my previously prepared options to all of them. But my options get appended only to the last select, no matter how many selects there are.

The console reports that it did iterate through all selects...

HTML:

```
Number of:
<input type="text" onkeyup="appendSelects(this.value);" />
<div id="container"></div>
<select style="display:none;" id="sample">
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#container').html('');
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    $('#container').append('<select id="'+i+'"></select>');
}

var options = $('#sample option').clone();
$('#container select').each(function(){
   $(this).append(options);
    console.log('appended options to '+$(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Fiddle is located here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Ck9Wb/1/

Where did i go wrong?

Comment: append will move your element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you were appending the same dom element instance to multiple elements

```
window.appendSelects = function(n) {
    $('#container').html('');
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        $('#container').append('<select id="'+i+'"></select>');
    }

    var options = $('#sample').html();
    $('#container select').html(options);
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7LNQh/)

Answer (score 1):

```
window.appendSelects = function(n) {
    $('#container').html('');
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        $('#container').append('<select id="'+i+'"></select>');
    }

    var options = $('#sample').html();// get by id because here we get option html 
    $('#container select').html(options);
}
```

see [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ck9Wb/12/)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `clone()` at the point of declaring the `options` variable, which only results in one set being cloned, and then moved between the newly created `select` elements, you need to `clone()` when appending to the selects:

```
var options = $('#sample option');
$('#container select').each(function(){
   $(this).append(options.clone()); // clone here...
    console.log('appended options to '+$(this).attr('id'));
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/Ck9Wb/9/)